# Display Products in shopping cart in a drop down format in Magento

Tags: blocks, shopping-cart

copy file of sidebar.phtml file in path `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart` paste in mytheme  name is `cart_top.phtml` path is `mythmeme\template\checkout\cart`
add the code in my `header.phtml` file. `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/cart_top.phtml')->toHtml()."Mycart"; ?>` add this code in my `header.phtml` but block is not working. can you tell me what the issue?

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaydipsinh Parmar
you can do using  xml

create `local.xml` at `app/design/frontend/your_package/our_theme/layout/` and past the code

```
       <default>

   <reference name="header">

        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_header" template="checkout/cart/cart_top.phtml" >
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
 </reference>    </default>
```

then `add the  echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar_header') to header.phtml`

Comment: but i want call my custom template cart_top.phtml then what you doing?

Comment: also i add this in my local.xml file call in header.phtml file but not working.

Comment: hey are you want change just sideber template file or call sidebar bar on header

Comment: if you want to call sidebar on  header... then you can try my code.. i have missing <default>

Comment: remove cart sidebar in sidebar i do code `<remove name="cart_sidebar"></remove>` in local.xml file it can be issue with your code that's not working

Comment: i have create replicate of cart sidebar and my sidebar name is   to did not effectit on <remove name="cart_sidebar"></remove>.you <remove name="cart_sidebar"></remove> remove default sidebar

Comment: sorry but i paste your code in local.xml file and header.phtml. but not working. i am also working with sidebar.phtml that's why not working. also not given any error. i don't undestand what is the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16916/discussion-between-jaydipsinh-parmar-and-amit-bera).